# Backbone - Updating models in collection with data polled from another API

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a Backbone collection that I'm populating from an API endpoint. This return data such as:

```
[
    {
        "gameId": 1234,
        "gameName": "Fun Game 1"
    },
    {
        "gameId": 1235,
        "gameName": "Fun Game 2"
    },
    {
        "gameId": 1236,
        "gameName": "Fun Game 3"
    },
    etc,
    etc,
    etc
]
```

The collection is very simple and is initialised in the router so it's accessible to the entire app:

```
var GamesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: GameModel,
        url: '/path/to/games/list',

        parse:function(response){
            return response;
        }
    });
```

I have another endpoint that returns a collection of data related to the original data. This data looks like:

```
[
    {
        "gameId": 1234,
        "numberOfPlayers": "1,000"
    },
    {
        "gameId": 1235,
        "numberOfPlayers": "Fun Game 2"
    },
    {
        "gameId": 9999,
        "numberOfPlayers": "Some other game that's not in the original list"
    }
]
```

Note that the `number of players` response may or may not contain data for every game in the original response and may or may not contain data for games that do not exist in the original games response.

I need to be poll the `number of players` endpoint every X minutes and update the models in the GamesCollection with the data from the response so I can show this in the view.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query your `numberOfPlayers` endpoint and then [`set` the fetched data  on your collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set). You can customize how `set` works with `add` and `remove` options.

For example,

```
var GamesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: GameModel,
    url: '/path/to/games/list',

    parse: function(response){
        return response;
    },

    pollNumberOfPlayers: function() {
        var self = this;
        return Backbone.ajax('/numberOfPlayers/endpoint').then(function(resp) {
            self.set(resp, {add: false, remove: false, merge: true});
        });
    },

    startPolling: function() {
        var self = this, 
            timer = 10000; //10 seconds

        self.pollNumberOfPlayers().then(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                self.startPolling();
            }, timer);
        });
    }
});
```

Note that I assumed your `GameModel` objects have `gameId` as their `idAttribute`.